# Strange timeline on ClientConnected and ClientDoneRequest

Tags: fiddler

I'm on help debugging a friend's site which is complained have a long connection time.
When try inspecting it with Fiddler I saw the ClientDoneRequest and ClientConnected is quite strange :

```
URI requested : /

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:        11:40:07.859
ClientBeginRequest:     11:40:33.687
ClientDoneRequest:      11:40:33.687
Gateway Determination:  0ms
DNS Lookup:             0ms
TCP/IP Connect:         65ms
HTTPS Handshake:        0ms
ServerConnected:        11:40:33.750
FiddlerBeginRequest:    11:40:33.750
ServerGotRequest:       11:40:33.750
ServerBeginResponse:    11:40:33.687
ServerDoneResponse:     11:40:44.031
ClientBeginResponse:    11:40:44.031
ClientDoneResponse:     11:40:44.031
    Overall Elapsed:    00:00:10.3437500
```

As you can see, ClientDoneRequest - ClientConnected is approx to 30s ...

I have checked around but have no idea what lead to this problem
Somebody point me out please :S
Thanks

P/S : Fiddler version 2.3.0.0

Answer (score 4):

http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/cd325dea517acc1d

That's entirely expected in cases where the client's request was sent 
on a reused client socket. ClientConnected refers to the connection 
time of the socket connection from the browser to Fiddler. Because 
those socket connections may be reused, you can often see cases where 
ClientConnected is even minutes earlier than ClientBeginRequest, 
because the socket was originally connected for, say, request #1, and 
then later reused for, say, request #12 a few seconds later, then 
request #20 about 20 seconds later, and later request #35 nearly a 
minute later, etc.

By default, a client socket is kept alive if it is reused within 30 
seconds (pref named 
"fiddler.network.timeouts.clientpipe.receive.reuse") of the previous 
request.

Comment: Thanks EricLaw for the answer, But seem it's not Fiddler and/or client socket's issue.
I think it's from the server's config because it get happened on all tested browsers => That's why we try Fiddler to investigate but still have no clue

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled upon this question, and then this related web page that described what all the timing entries mean:

http://fiddler.wikidot.com/timers